# Is there going to be a Popular Profile badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, badge-request

Is there going to be a Popular Profile badge?

Imagine the situation:

- when the total unique visitors of
  some guy's personal profile is greater
  than 10.000 in a week or something
  like that he could earn a badge for
  that.

Comment: 10,000 views in a *week*?. Mine hasn't had 3,000 views in nearly 20 months.

Comment: @ChrisF - guess we're not popular enough.

Comment: I used my profile to give away 3 free MSDN Ultimate subscriptions, 12K$ list price each.  Took almost 2 weeks.  Didn't make it any more popular either :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sole purpose of badges on Stackoverflow is **to encourage desired behaviors**. All the badges reward a behavior that should be encouraged as it helps the site. Posting good questions, answers, editing posts to make them better, popularizing the site, etc.

Do we really want to encourage people to be profile whores? This encourages behavior like trying to elevate yourself above everyone else in bad ways. I don't think the profile view counter was intended to be used for competition.

Comment: This. A popular profile badge would be as likely to be won by user who engage in persistent misbehavior (because of empowered users checking the profile to determine how strongly to react) as those who are genuinely helpful.